# Change type of one data in panda dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, types

I am trying to do text preprocessing but I found out that one single data in my `text` column contains `float`.

```
i=0
while True:
    for each in list_df['text']:
        print(type(list_df['text'][i]))
        i+=1
```

[image]

How can I change this into str?

Comment: `df['text'].astype(str)` to cast the entire column to strings. you can check by using `apply` `df['text'].astype(str).apply(type)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `col_x` is your column name, try:

```
df['col_x'] = df['col_x'].astype(str)
```